# Select class using switch-case statement in Razor view

Tags: css, razor, model-view-controller

I want to change class name based on value of `WhichColor` property. If it's 1 it should be red, if it's 2 it's blue and so on. I know how to do this for two colors with `:?` statement. But what if I have more?

I've tried to do it with switch case but it doesn't allow me to return string I probably don't understand how switch case works in this scenario.

```
<td class="@{
        switch (item.WhichColor)
        {
            case 1:
                return "red";
            case 2:
                return "blue";
            case 3:
                return "green";
            default:
                break;
        }
            } ">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WhichColor)
    </td>
```

I want for it to work like the switch-case above but it doesn't allow me to return string. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to do it with combined tenary statements:

```
<td class="@(
        (item.WhichColor == 1) ? "green" : (item.WhichColor == 2) ? "yellow" : (item.WhichColor == 3) ? "red" : (item.WhichColor == 4) ? "blue" : (item.WhichColor == 5 ? "gray" : "")
            )">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WhichColor)
    </td>
```